# Compilation error while getting address of a variable selected using ternary operator

Tags: c, gcc

I am compiling below by getting address of a variable which was selected using a ternary operator. I am getting below error.

> error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand.

```
#define GETINT() ((a==1) ? b : c)
void main()
{
   int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
   int *ptr = &GETINT();

   printf("%d\n", *ptr);
}
```

I have lot of instances like this in my code, so i am expecting a solution which would involve probably just changing the macro alone, but not as `#define GETINT() ((a==1) ? &b : &c)`, as i am using this to select the integer among b and c in few other places in my code. In-case if there is no solution can anyone explain what's wrong with it. BTW, this code got compiled with Green Hills C compiler but giving problem in GCC 4.8

Comment: Expanding a little on existing answers - the conditional `? :` expression is evaluated at run-time. It returns a value which need not have a specific address (typically, it will be in a CPU register). So in general, the `&` can't guarantee to give a sensible address for the result - which is approximately why the result is defined to be an "rvalue" rather than an "lvalue".

Answer (score 2):

The problem is exactly what the compiler says, that the argument to `&` must be an lvalue, and you pass an expression using `?:` instead.

You also can't do this, for the same reason:

```
((a == 1) ? b : c) = 4711;  /* BAD CODE */
```

You really should include the `&` inside the macro, and just dereference when you want the actual value:

```
#define GETINTPTR(a)  ((a == 1) ? &b : &c)
#define GETINT(a)     *GETINTPTR(a)
```

Of course the `GETINT()` macro is kind of silly and you could just use `*GETINTPTR()` directly in your code.

Comment: Thanks unwind, ((a == 1) ? b : c) = 4711; this made me understand the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As per the `C11` standards, chapter 6.5.15, conditional expression,

> *[...]* the result is the **value** of the second or third operand
>   (whichever is evaluated), converted to the type described below.<sup>(110)</sup>

and, realted, footnote (110)

> A conditional expression does not yield an lvalue.

OTOH, as per chapter 6.5.3.2, (emphasis mine)

> The **operand of the unary `&` operator** shall be either a function designator, the result of a [] or unary * operator, or **an lvalue** that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is not declared with the register storage-class  pecifier.

So, your code is not valid.

Solution: Write your MACRO like

```
 #define GETINT(a,b,c) ((a==1) ? &b : &c)
```

and use it like

```
int *ptr = GETINT(a,b,c);
```

Comment: Although, notes are not normative. The normative text that says what you want would be `result is the value of the second or third operand` emphasis on *value*.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour sir, I just quoted the related footnote. However, as per your suggestion,updated my asnwer. Hope it's better now.

Answer (score 1):

If you expand `&GETINT()` you get

```
&((a==1) ? b : c)
```

and this is not valid C.

You need this:

```
#define GETINT() ((a==1) ? &b : &c)
....
int *ptr = GETINT();
```

Comment: Isn't the question why this isn't valid?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed the issue, by just changing macro alone which serves both of my purposes.
    #define GETINT() (*((a==1) ? &b : &c))

Below is the code now,

```
#define GETINT() (*((a==1) ? &b : &c))
void main()
{
   int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
   int *ptr = &GETINT();
   int d = GETINT();

   printf("%d %d\n", *ptr, d);
}
```